# Why does sendKeys not send every character at anytime?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, vps, sendkeys

I wrote a method that enters Strings in web elements on different websites.
Until now everything was working, but after I have switched to running the program on my VPS, sendKeys (method to enter the keys) does not send every character anymore.

Example:

```
wanted string:!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

these characters do not appear in the web element:$%456^

but in another string, some of these characters work again.
If I enter z43 every character appears in the element although the character "4" was not delivered in the previous string above.

After using a method that sends every Character as a Char on its own and additionally prints it, I realized that sendKeys tries to enter the keys, but they do not arrive.

I would be very glad if some of you help me. :)

System on which everything was working: Windows 10, java, eclipse, selenium, chromedriver

A system with failure: VPS, Linux ubuntu 20.04, remote desktop via vncviewer, connected with putty, java, eclipse, selenium, chromedriver

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML and your code trials.

Comment: I can not do that